# Is there a way in JavaScript to retrieve the form data that *would* be sent with a form without submitting it?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

If I have an HTML form, let’s say...

```
<form id='myform'>
    <input type='hidden' name='x' value='y'>
    <input type='text' name='something' value='Type something in here.'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

... and then I use jQuery to respond to the form submission event, e.g.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    ...
    return false;
});
```

Now suppose I want to submit the form as an AJAX call instead of actually submitting it the “traditional” way (as a new page). Is there an easy way to get a JS object containing the data that would be sent, which I can pass into `$.post()`? So in the above example it would look something like...

```
{
    x: 'y',
    something: 'Type something in here.'
}
```

or do I have to bake my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) method.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function () {
           //
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: That produces a string, not a JS object. Is it possible to pass that string into `$.post()`?

Comment: @Timwi: You sure can, `jQuery.post(this.action /* url */, $(this).serialize(), /* callback */)`. The closest you can get to getting an object returned is to use [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray)... which returns an array of encoded form elements.

Answer (score 2):

As you're already using jQuery, use [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    var data = $form.serialize();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That produces a string, not a JS object. Is it possible to pass that string into `$.post()`?

Comment: Yes, just pass it as 2nd argument `$.post(url, data, callback);`